# Bootstrap Data-bs-toggle is not working in the currently version?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I notice that bootstrap 5.1.3 data-bs-toggle isn't working anymore. Like in this exemple:

```
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" datadat-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

If you use the data-bs-toggle="dropdown" it just doens't work. **I would like to know if this is happening with you too and why is that? Maybe the version 5.1.3 has some kind of bug?**
Here is the bootstrap official page for this NavBar component example:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know what I was doing wrong...
While working on my project, I was using a minimal version of bootstrap that my teacher provided me, and he was using it with lower version bootstrap, so data-bs-toggle was not working...
:) thanks for the answers

Comment: You can answer your question if this solves it

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo:

Switch "datadat-bs-toggle" to "data-bs-toggle"